# FabricJS: Center new object in canvas after zoom and change size

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, fabricjs

I'm using FabricJS 1.7.9 and when I load my canvas it has an initial size of 216x216 pixels which has text elements. When I insert an SVG object with a width of 90px, I use a function which allows me center this object in the canvas:

```
function insert_svg(url) {
  fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url,function(objects, options){
    var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    obj.scaleToWidth(90).set({ 
      borderColor: '#eaeaea',
      cornerColor: '#eaeaea',
      cornerSize: 10,
      cornerStyle: 'circle',
      transparentCorners: false,
      lockUniScaling: true,
      id: newID,
      url_svg: url
    });

    canvas.centerObjectH(obj);
    canvas.centerObjectV(obj);

    canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
  });
}


insert_svg("https://myurl/img/objeto.svg");
```

Example:

[image]

If I change the canvas size I also modify the zoom for the previous object to fit proportionally. For example, I'm going to change canvas size to 320x320:

```
function canvas_size(setWidth,setHeight) {
   canvas.setHeight(parseInt(setHeight));
   canvas.setWidth(parseInt(setWidth));


   var sz = setWidth / 216;
   sz = parseFloat(sz);
   canvas.setZoom(sz);
   canvas.renderAll();
}

canvas_size(320,320);
```

Result:

[image]

The problem occurs when after having done the resizing and zooming, and I want to insert a new svg object, it is not centered correctly. How do I fix it?

I tried changing the function:

```
function insert_svg(url) {
  fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url,function(objects, options){
    var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    obj.scaleToWidth(90).set({ 
      borderColor: '#eaeaea',
      cornerColor: '#eaeaea',
      cornerSize: 10,
      cornerStyle: 'circle',
      transparentCorners: false,
      lockUniScaling: true,
      id: newID,
      url_svg: url
    });

     var targetWidth = 90;
     var scaleX = targetWidth / obj.width;
     var scaleY = targetWidth / obj.height;
     var scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
     obj.scale(scale);

     // Adjust
     var newWidth = parseInt(canvas.width); // new canvas width 
     var newHeight = parseInt(canvas.height); // new canvas height
     canvas.setWidth(newWidth);
     canvas.setHeight(newHeight);

     
     var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
     var centerY = canvas.height / 2;

     
     var leftOffset = (obj.width * obj.scaleX) / 2;
     var topOffset = (obj.height * obj.scaleY) / 2;
     var left = centerX - leftOffset;
     var top = centerY - topOffset;


     obj.set({ left: left, top: top });
     canvas.add(obj).renderAll();

     canvas.centerObjectH(obj);
     canvas.centerObjectV(obj);


  });
}
```

I obtain this when I insert a new SVG object:

[image]

And I want the new SVG object centered like this:

[image]

How can I fix it?

I'd like to receive your help.